# Look at my JSON, my data is not showing in the UI

Tags: java, android, json

This is my J-SON parsing i don't understand where i am making mistake  . Anyone please look at the code and tell me what i am doing wrong.I also provided the J-SON URL

```
private Weather extractFeatureFromJSON (String json_incoming){
    Weather sendInformation = null ;
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json_incoming);
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

        long timeReceived = jsonObject.getLong("EpochTime");
        String weatherStatusReceived = jsonObject.getString("WeatherText");
        boolean DayOrNightReceived = jsonObject.getBoolean("IsDayTime");
        JSONObject fetchTemperature = new JSONObject("Temperature");
        JSONObject dive_deep_t = fetchTemperature.getJSONObject("Metric");
        double tempReceived = dive_deep_t.getDouble("Value");
        JSONObject fetch_RF_Temperature = new JSONObject("RealFeelTemperature");
        JSONObject dive_deep_t1 = fetch_RF_Temperature.getJSONObject("Metric");
        double RF_tempReceived = dive_deep_t1.getDouble("Value");
        JSONObject fetch_wind = new JSONObject("Wind");
        JSONObject fetch_wind_direction = fetch_wind.getJSONObject("Direction");
        int directionDegreeReceived = fetch_wind_direction.getInt("Degrees");
        String in_which_direction = fetch_wind_direction.getString("Localized");
        JSONObject fetch_wind_speed = fetch_wind.getJSONObject("Speed");
        JSONObject fetch_wind_speed_in_metrics = fetch_wind_speed.getJSONObject("Metric");
        double speedReceived = fetch_wind_speed_in_metrics.getDouble("Value");

        int i = Integer.parseInt(in_which_direction);
        int directionAndInWhich = directionDegreeReceived + i;

        return new Weather(tempReceived , RF_tempReceived , DayOrNightReceived , weatherStatusReceived ,timeReceived  , speedReceived , directionAndInWhich);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null ;
}
```

> http://dataservice.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/257072?apikey=JTgPZ8wN9VUy07GaOODeZfZ3sAM12irH&language=en-us&details=true

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to create new JsonObjects like new JSONObject("Temperature"); and not just get them?

Comment: nope . no run time error and compile error . the data i fetch is not display !

Comment: if i look at the url . There Temperature is object so i must store it in the JSON object right ? @petul then retrieve its value into int

Comment: @AnonymousHacker check my below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `getJSONObject` from `jsonObject` instead of creating `new JSONObject`

To get `Temperature, RealFeelTemperature, Wind` Object you need to use

```
jsonObject.getJSONObject("Temperature");
jsonObject.getJSONObject("RealFeelTemperature");
jsonObject.getJSONObject("Wind");
```

Not new `JSONObject`

```
new JSONObject("Temperature");
new JSONObject("RealFeelTemperature");
new JSONObject("Wind");
```